# Grpc .NET server, Python client: Failed to connect, UNKOWN

Tags: python, .net, ssl, grpc

I have made a Grpc server and client in .NET successfully. I am trying to recreate the client from Python. In .NET I had to create these channelOptions to not return SSL errors. I am not able to reproduce these options in python. I have tried using `channel = grpc.insecure_channel('127.0.0.1:5001')` and receive the same status code and that it is unavailable. Although, that error is present I can run the .NET client fine.

I am using `$ python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I../../protos --python_out=. --pyi_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ../../protos/route_guide.proto` to populate the pb2.py and pb2_grpc.py files from the proto file in my .NET application. Do I need to build out the .proto file with syntax specifying a Python client?

//.NET

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
};

var channelOptions = new GrpcChannelOptions
{
    HttpHandler = handler
};

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://127.0.0.1:5001",channelOptions);
```

//Python

```
options = [('grpc.ssl_target_name_override', '127.0.0.1')]
creds = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()
channel = grpc.secure_channel("127.0.0.1:5001", creds, options)
```

//Error

```
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
details = "failed to connect to all addresses; 
last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:127.0.0.1:5001: 
Ssl handshake failed: SSL_ERROR_SSL: 
error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED"
debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:failed to connect to all addresses;
last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:127.0.0.1:5001: Ssl handshake failed: 
SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with gRPC on .NET. Is the .NET server definitely serving on a TLS endpoint? Your server code includes `https://` but you don't include other references to TLS certificates. Could it be that the Python client is failing because it should use an insecure connection instead (`grpc.insecure_channel("...")`)? One way to sanity check this is to use a known-good gRPC client such as [gRPCurl](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl) to test the server.

Comment: I am serving to 5001, https://, and 5000, http:// both are not able to connect with the python code. I have tried grpc.insecure. I have made a .NET client and am able to call methods successfully. I'll investigate further with gRPCurl. Thank you for the reply and reference.

Comment: Both work with .NET client, I assume. Have you tried gRPCurl or Postman as a sanity check (.NET client)?

Comment: Do I need the actual .proto file in my python project? I am using `$ python -m grpc_tools.protoc -I../../protos --python_out=. --pyi_out=. --grpc_python_out=. ../../protos/route_guide.proto` to route the .proto file from my .NET project in to the Python project and creating pb2.py and  pb2_grpc.py files.

Comment: What you've done is correct.

Comment: The errors suggest the client is unable to connect to the server. It's unclear which of the errors is the root cause. Some errors (`failed to connect` `UNKNOWN: ipv4:127.0.0.1:5001`) suggest the client can't reach the server's socket. Other errors suggest the connection succeeds but the `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED`. It's confusing. This is why I proposed using a known-good client to test the server to remove the server as part of the problem.

Comment: It works in postman. I had to use a secured connection. Not certain how to reproduce these results.

Comment: OK! Are you using Linux? Windows? Mac?

Comment: I am using Windows. I have just used OpenSSL to generate a .csr and .key, but failing to attribute them in a python def and in .ConfigureWebHostDefaults.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I needed to specify "Http2" protocol in the appsettings.json.

Here is my example repo.
https://github.com/ifTaylor/grpc_pynet

```
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://localhost:5000",
        "Protocols": "Http2"
      }
    }
  }
```